# I was trying to find the total no. of digits that appear up till a certain number and my code is going wrong when the input is 10^9

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
  
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
      
        //write your code here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = sc.nextInt();
// For each Iteration I am adding the total no. of
// 1's place digits, 10's place digits, 100's place digits, and so on.
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            int Num = sc.nextInt();
            int count = 0;
            for(int j=1;j<=Num;j*=10){
                count += Num-j+1; 
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Input:
3
100
1000000000
222222222

The output I am seeing:
192
298954307
1888888896

Desired Output:
192
8888888899
1888888896

Comment: Please don't just throw poorly formatted code at us but add at least some text, e.g. describe your thinking, what you want to achieve (ideally add examples), how you want to achieve it, wwhether you already stepped through your code with a debugger etc.

Comment: @user16320675 10^9 would still be a valid value for `int` as its maximum value would be about 2.14 * 10^9.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for helping me out. I am a beginner and I haven't considered the maximum value that can be contained in an Int. As far as my code goes the output for 10^9 is larger than what an int can hold and that's where I am getting the wrong output

Comment: @Gardener I got the same output but the output is actually wrong

Comment: Note that if you really expect `count` to hold the value 8888888899 then the type `int` won't suffice. You'll need `long` in that case.

Answer (score -1):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        //write your code here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            int Num = sc.nextInt();
            long count = 0;
            for(int j=1;j<=Num;j*=10){
                count += Num-j+1; 
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

I just needed to change the `count` variable from `int` to `long`.